# PMML and time-series

Tags: time-series, pmml

What is the purpose for embedding the original and predicted time series in PMML models (http://www.dmg.org/v4-1/TimeSeriesModel.html)? I don't understand how these embedded series are being used by the two official examples in the link.

The first example embeds the original time series used for fitting, and some predicted values. However, these series don't seem to be used for forecasting (i.e., the DA-M formula).

Similarly, the second example embeds a bunch of time values under the ExponentialElement, but they don't seem to be used by the Brown formula for forecasting.